# Spark Streaming : What is the difference between countByValueAndWindow() and countByWindow()?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand window transformations on Spark DStream in Spark Streaming.

Can someone give a real time example or clear example that can differentiate `countByWindow()` and `countByValueAndWindow()`

Also when to use what?